# SVG - Offset an open path dynamically with Javascript

Tags: svg, filter, path, gradient, offset

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957670/adjust-vertical-position-of-a-stroke-inside-another-stroke/76964548). This question is closer to the problem I'm trying to solve. I would like also to document the different approaches I've tried to solve the problem.

Given a certain **open** path, I would like to be able to generate dynamically a path that would follow the initial path, but be offset by a certain value. **To clarify: I am not looking for the value of the path (`d` attribute). It could be done using masks/clipping for example.**

What I would like to achieve (approximation):

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w87Ka.png)

Here is what I tried:

- Generating an offset path with [Bezier.js](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/) and [normalize-svg-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-svg-path) : This is the best solution I could come up with. However, there is some significant artifact, as you can see in this image: [Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NQ0Z.png)
- Using `transform` attribute: While it seemed like a good idea, it was hard to generate the values of this attribute dynamically, and it would not work with all paths.
- Using a gradient: I would have thought that using a linear gradient and `stop-opacity` would make this problem very easy. However, gradients don't work across paths.
- Using clipping/[masks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723835/10274385): It works, however the generated segment can only be centered on the initial path. I was not able to offset the segment.
- Using [filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46176006/10274385): I was very hopeful I could find a solution with filters, but I had the same problem as with clipping and masks.